# Android NDK Aborting Stop, Failed to create NDK build

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, ndk-build

[image]

```
# Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# this file is included from prebuilt-shared-library.mk or
# prebuilt-static-library.mk to declare prebuilt library binaries.
#

$(call assert-defined, LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT LOCAL_MAKEFILE LOCAL_PREBUILT_PREFIX LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX)

$(call check-defined-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT))
$(call check-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE))
$(call check-LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME)

# Check that LOCAL_SRC_FILES contains only the path to one library
ifneq ($(words $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)),1)
$(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE): The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one item))
$(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
endif

bad_prebuilts := $(filter-out %$(LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX),$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
ifdef bad_prebuilts
$(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE): LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with "$(LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX)")
$(call __ndk_info,The following file is unsupported: $(bad_prebuilts))
$(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
endif

prebuilt_path := $(call local-prebuilt-path,$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
prebuilt := $(strip $(wildcard $(prebuilt_path)))

ifndef prebuilt
$(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE): LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file)
$(call __ndk_info,Check that $(prebuilt_path) exists, or that its path is correct)
$(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
endif

# If LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME is defined, it will be used to name the file
# in the TARGET_OUT directory, and then the installation one. Note that
# it shouldn't have an .a or .so extension nor contain directory separators.
#
# If the variable is not defined, we determine its value from LOCAL_SRC_FILES
#
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := $(strip $(LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME))
ifndef LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME
    LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := $(notdir $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
    LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := $(LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME:%$(LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX)=%)
endif
$(eval $(call ev-check-module-filename))

# If LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE is not defined, then ensure that the prebuilt is
# copied to TARGET_OUT during the build.
LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE := $(strip $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE))
ifndef LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE
  LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE := $(TARGET_OUT)/$(LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME)$(LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX)
  LOCAL_OBJECTS      := $(prebuilt)

  $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE): $(LOCAL_OBJECTS)
endif

LOCAL_OBJS_DIR  := $(TARGET_OBJS)/$(LOCAL_MODULE)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=

include $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/build-module.mk
```

I am getting NDK Aborting Stop error in this prebuilt-library.mk file. The file is given above. It's also showing failed to build NDK & NDK-build finished with non zero exit value 2.

How can I fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the rest of the error message.  All we know from that is it failed, not what it was doing when it did.

Comment: @GabeSechan posted the image.

Comment: @AvijitKarmakar Please make sure that your Android project and NDK path does not contain white space.

Comment: @Lawrance I have already checked that. There is no space in Android project & NDK path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: If you already created project and after that you are installing Android NDK, CMake and LLDB through SDK Tools then your project might not build i.e you will get an error while **Make Project**.

Follow the below steps:

1. Install Android NDK, CMake and LLDB
2. Create New Project in Android and checked **Include C++ Support**[image]
3. At last Enable **Exception Support** & **Runtime Type information Support**[image]
4. Press to Finish.

In app level `build.gradle` file.

- Add below lines before your `apply plugin:...`

  ```
  import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

  Properties properties = new Properties()
  properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
  def ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
  ```
- Add in `android` -> `defaultConfig`

  externalNativeBuild{
      cmake{
          cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
      }
  }
- Add below lines after `buildTypes {}` tag

  externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
          path "CMakeLists.txt"
      }
  }
  task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
      if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
          commandLine ndkDir + '/ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
      } else {
          commandLine ndkDir + '/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
      }
  }

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
      compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
  }

Hope it helps you. !!