# Android NDK: Assertion failure: LOCAL_MAKEFILE is not defined

Tags: android, gradle, makefile, android-ndk

I was trying to build a project and when I execute a gradle task to build, I'm receiving the folllow error:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.2.6472646/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:20: *** Android NDK:  Assertion failure: LOCAL_MAKEFILE is not defined    .  Stop.
```

I never used NDK before, and I'm not sure where I need to start.

Apparently `LOCAL_MAKEFILE` is not defined, but where should I define it?

Follows below, line 20 of prebuilt-library file:

```
    15  
    16  # this file is included from prebuilt-shared-library.mk or
    17  # prebuilt-static-library.mk to declare prebuilt library binaries.
    18  #
    19  
    20  $(call assert-defined, LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT LOCAL_MAKEFILE LOCAL_PREBUILT_PREFIX LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX)
    21  
    22  $(call check-defined-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT))
    23  $(call check-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE))
    24  $(call check-LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME)
    25
```

Somebody have any idea what's going on?

Every help is welcome!

Thanks for now!

Comment: Check this question , same your problem [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572012/android-ndk-aborting-stop-failed-to-create-ndk-build)

Comment: I read this answer before post my question. I tried to follow the steps but I think that we are facing differents issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve that issue, I need to remove all the NDK version and using only the  19 and 20 versions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On NDK r21d the same error. Thanks [Dan Albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632035/dan-albert) for the [patch](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/ndk/+/1317622/2/build/core/definitions.mk).
This fixes the error:

in **build/core/definitions.mk** change the line:

```
local-makefile = $(lastword $(filter %Android.mk,$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

to

```
_last_android_mk = $(lastword $(filter %Android.mk,$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
_last_non_ndk_makefile = $(lastword $(filter-out $(NDK_ROOT)%,$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
local-makefile = $(if $(_last_android_mk),$(_last_android_mk),$(_last_non_ndk_makefile))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1267. It will be fixed in an upcoming version of the NDK. The problem only presents when your main Android.mk file isn't actually named Android.mk.